# MS Word - Close Word when you close the last open document **using keyboard**

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

In MS Word, by default, you can use:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close Word
>    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close the current document

Is it possible to make Word close when you close the last open document?

For instance, in Chrome, if you keep hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> you'll eventually close the last tab, which will also close Chrome.  I'd like the same functionality with Word (and the other Office products) where I can just keep closing documents until I close the last one, at which point the application closes.  Unfortunately, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> doesn't close Word, even when there are no documents open.

Comment: Doesn't word already close when you close all the documents?

Comment: No, Ctrl+F4 doesn't close Word, does it? I believe Ctrl+F4 is equivalent to Ctrl+W. But Alt+F4 does close it, of course.

Comment: @ardentsonata: No, at least not Word 2010.

Comment: Perhaps you can look into writing a macro for this (close current doc, and if none exists then the app itself) and assign it to Ctrl+W.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer that you are looking for is Microsoft Word's **FileCloseOrExist** command.

It does exactly what you want.  If you have 2 documents open and you execute the FileCloseOrExit command, then only the active document closes.  When you execute the FileCloseOrExit command a second time now when only 1 document is open, it will close the last document and then terminate Microsoft Word.

Whenever I install Microsoft Word on a new computer, one of the first things I do is change the hotkey, Control+W from FileClose to FileCloseOrExit.  To be honest, I don't know why they even have FileClose.  FileCloseOrExist is the same thing but adds terminating Microsoft Word with the last document.  It's much better.

To change the Control+W hotkey to this command, you need to:

1. Select **File** which is the first menu selection located at the top left.
2. Select **Options** that is the last selection in the File menu.
3. The Word Options window appears with a list on the left.  Select **Customize Ribbon** that is located 4th from the bottom.
4. 2 lists will appear in the window.  Click **Customize** that is at the bottom of the left list.  It's immediately right of the text that says, "Keyboard shortcuts:".
5. Under Categories, scroll all the way to the bottom.  Click "**All Commands**" and the Command list to the right will show all possible commands.  Scroll down the alphabetized list to **FileCloseOrExit**.
6. Input **Control+W** as the hotkey.  Click the **Assign button** at the bottom left.

There you have it.  Now, every time you press Control+W in Microsoft Word, the program will automatically exit the program when you close the last document instead of leaving an ugly blank Word program.

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thanks John!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Well, not sure if it is worth the effort writing a macro or special code for this when <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> closes Word with the last open Word document.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the consensus.  Thanks.